# Need help identifying a fantasy trilogy with a young woman protagonist

Tags: story-identification

I cannot remember the author's name nor the titles of any of the books.

What I do remember is that the main character is a young woman who, I believe, dreams of an alternate reality.  There are hints throughout that the dream is really happening.

I do recall one scene in which the young woman finds a magician from this alternate reality in her kitchen.  I know it's not much to go on but any help is appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: When did you read these books? How old were they? Were they in English? Where/when were they set? What else happens to the young woman - can you remember anything about the overall plot? See also [our](http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/a/9337/31394) [guidance](http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/a/9336/31394) on asking good story-ID questions.

Comment: See OP confirmation comment for answer below.

Answer (score 5):

This classically sounds like Barbara Hambly's *The Time of the Dark*. It was originally published 1982, but definitely has been reprinted. Here's a short description from Hambly's [website](http://www.barbarahambly.com/hambooks.htm):

> For Gil, it started with the dreams; of a city being abandoned because
>   of some nameless horror that was slowly invading, and of the wizard
>   Ingold, who later appeared in her kitchen. For Rudy, it started with
>   an ill-fated beer run that linked him with Gil and Ingold and drew him
>   into a world unlike his, where the infamous Dark was invading. A world
>   where academic Gil became a warrior and punk/artist Rudy a mage, and
>   where everyone was working to reach a haven from the Dark.

The story continues in *The Walls of Air* and *The Armies of Daylight*. There are two following books, *Mother of Winter* and *Icefalcon's Quest*. They were published 13 and 11 years later.

Comment: Thank you very much.  That is exactly the series I was looking for.

Comment: I'm glad to be of help! Bev, if you haven't yet, could you mark the answer as correct so your question won't be listed as "unanswered." Thanks!